# How to get data of a csv file row by row in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, csv

I am having a csv file which looks like a xl file(format) but the extension is .csv

I am writing   a code which converts each row of the csv file to json and sends to a server (or logs out). But the file changes frequently so i am using fs.watch to watch changes, here changes means adding new rows, so i want to send only newly added rows to server  each time an event is thrown by fs.watch, i can send only new rows if i get data from csv row by row and convert it to json and send to server, i can keep track of last row sent and when an event occurred i will start sending from last saved row.

I want a way to get row by row data from csv file thats it i have tried many but none worked

I don't want solution only to below code, will accept any solution that does the work above

I am also ok with xl file solution as i can change the extension to .xlsx
Mycode:

```
var Papa = require('babyparse');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test.csv';
var content = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'binary' });
Papa.parse(content,{
    fs.watchFile('test.csv', function (curr, prev) {
    step: function(row){
        console.log("Row: ", row.data);



});

});
});
```

error:

```
fs.watchFile('test.csv', function (curr, prev) {
  ^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Comment: There are modules that already do this sort of thing.  For example: https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

Comment: Can you provide any sample code that explains because the link is not that clear, it will be helpful with sample code that explains about code

Comment: Look at the samples folder within the repo.